# Modiffy EntityManager generated by netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, persistence

I've generated `jtable` on netbeans using drag and drop from database services. Database is oracle xe.

Netbeans generates EntityManager,Query and list taking database connection from  persistence.xml file.

Aparently, it works fine as log as you don't change any detail of database connection.

netbeans generates something like this:

> BDPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null :
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BBDPU").createEntityManager();

and only works with the user and password that I used when I created the application. 
Does anybody know how to change user, password and data connection of these entitiesManager  generated by netbeans ?

Comment: BBDPU is the name of the persistence unit as specified in the persistence.xml ?

Comment: You shouldn't use drag and drop and code generation if you don't understand the code that the IDE generates for you. Take a huge step back, read a book or tutorial about JPA, then try to write code by yourself and then, and only then, see if using the IDE code generation makes it faster for you. Generating and using code that you don't understand will only lead to a failure.

Comment: yes BBDPU is the name of the persisence in persisence.xml.